# How to commit deleted file changes in Intellj IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, commit, delete-file

I have some file `sample_file.doc` which is visible in my IntelliJ IDEA.

If I delete `sample_file.doc` file from the local folder it disappear from IntelliJ IDEA, not allowing me to commit the deleted file changes.

I want to commit the deletion so that the deleted file change appear in Git repository.

Please advise how to commit deleted files in IntellJ IDEA?

Comment: What version Intellij IDEA you use? Just select commit in VCS menu and you will see modified and deleted file list to commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA open **View → Tool  Windows → Version Control**, or just press (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> on macOS) or (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> on Windows).

In Version Control panel make sure the **Local Changes** tab is selected:

[image]

- Grey color means deleted file
- Blue color means amended file
- Green color means a new file

There are other pretty handy VSC features that come out of the box with IDEA, for instance:

- (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on macOS) or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on Windows) to **Commit** your local changes

  - it the same dialog select file and press (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on macOS) or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on Windows) to **see the difference**
- (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on macOS) or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on Windows) to **Push** your commits. There is also an option on the right side of Push button to **Force Push**.
- meanwhile you can always press (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on macOS) or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows) to open **Revert Changes** window where checking diffs works as well

---

But you can also run a **Terminal** window right in IDEA by pressing

- <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> on macOS
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows

and use `git status` command to see what is going on:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Recent updates to IntelliJ (2019.3) have broken its ability to *easily* commit deletions.  Presently (2019.3), when you *only* delete a file, IntelliJ disables the commit option.

To trick IntelliJ, just make a trivial change to any other file, and then open the commit dialog.  Unselect the changed file, leaving only the deleted file selected, and then commit.  When finished, undo the change to the file you didn't delete.

Or just give up and do it from the command line (which is actually easier, but doesn't afford you some of the nicer dialog options, such as commit message history, etc.).

Comment: I reported this bug here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250489

Answer (score 2):

Deleted file are automatically added by git. You just need to commit and push them. 
Just for the sake of confirmation, run git status on the integrated terminal of intellij idea, and that should show the files as added.